# Http 500 error On using eclipse webservice explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I am using eclipse juno with java 7 version on my system.when I try to access websevice explorer.Then it gives HTTP 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Well HTTP 500 error means server error. So probably there is an issue with your project which is thrown may be in the process of project deploy or may be loading the home page. So better check all the dependencies first.

Comment: its not about a specific project . I am unable to launch web services explorer.